# Call to a member function persist() on null Symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm starting develop with Symfony, and I get this error on my code :
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGwNp.png)

There is my controller:

```
class MatierePremiereController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construc(EntityManagerInterface $em){
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/matiere_premiere", name="mp.index")
     * @param MatierePremiereRepository $repository
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(MatierePremiereRepository $repository): Response
    {
        $mp= $repository->findAll();
        return $this->render('matiere_premiere/index.html.twig', [
            'matierepremieres' => $mp
        ]);
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/matiere_premiere/new", name="matierepremiere.new")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $ez = new MatierePremiere();
        $ez = ['$ref'=>31, '$unite_mesure'=>'cm', '$stock'=>30, '$seuil_alert'=>4, '$seuil_critique'=>2, '$prix_ht'=>30];
        $this->em->persist($ez);
        $mp = new MatierePremiere();
        $form = $this->createForm(MatierePremiereFormType::class, $mp);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            //:dd($mp);
            $this->em->persist($mp);
            $this->em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('matierepremiere.list');


        }

        return $this->render('matiere_premiere/new.html.twig', [
            'matierepremiere' => $mp,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

(the using of "$ez" was for a test, the persist() error still here)

I would like some help, I've try several solution find on Forum, but nothing helped me!

Comment: You have an issue in your dependency injection. Can you add the part where you configure your controllers in services.yaml

Comment: public function __construc(

Answer (score 0):

The error is name of __construct() method, look at this:

```php
public function __construc(EntityManagerInterface $em){
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

please fix method name